# Query to find if a Parent has multiple items in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have the following table. How can I find if a Parent has multiple items.

For Eg: Parent 1 has items ABC and BBC, So the query should display '(Multiple)' instead of showing Item names. 
Parent 5 has only single item, It should show the Item name.

```
Price      |    Item    |  Parent
-----------|------------|-------------
20         |   ABC      |   1
10         |   BBC      |   1
5          |   CBC      |   5
21         |   DDB      |   6
17         |   BDD      |   6
31         |   DBB      |   6
```

I have created the following query which doesn't seems to be working.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN '(Multiple)' ELSE Item END FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(*), Item FROM Table WHERE Parent = @parent 
GROUP BY Item) Table GROUP BY Item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle below

```
SELECT distinct p.parent, case when p1.item is not null then 'MULTIPLE'
       else p.item end as txt
FROM product p 
left JOIN product p1 on p1.parent=p.parent and p1.item<>p.item
WHERE p.Parent = 6 --@parent
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e3612/29/0